# How to convert typescript class into JSON with surrounding string?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a TypeScript class named order. The generic structure is as follows:

```
export class Order {
    orderId : number= "";
    email : string = "";
    storeId : string = "";
    date : string = "";
    billing_address : Object = {};
    systemId : string = "";
    shipments : Object = {};
}
```

I want a way to convert this class into a JSON structure with a "order" key and the value being the fields of the order class. So it can look like this:

```
{
  "order":{
    "orderId":1232332,
    "date": "06/02/2016,
    etc....
   }
}
```

After doing a quick test while writing this question, can I simply do `let order_json = {"order": order};` and then later called `JSON.stringify(order_json)` to send it over an HTTP connection? My understanding is a JSON structure is simply a Javascript object in a particular format. Is this correct?

Comment: "can I simply do let order_json = {"order": order}; and then later called JSON.stringify(order_json) to send it over an http connection?". Have you tried yet?

Comment: I was able to get the first part to work.  I don't have the POST set up yet in Angular so unable to test the stringify feature (Although it does look fine in the console), but the creation seems to work.  I was expecting issues with this approach as it seemed too "simple"?

Comment: Doing class -> JSON is easy, but you can't automate the deserializing of a JSON to a specific case class I'm afraid. It's one of the many reasons classes suck :p  You will have to write a deserializer yourself:  MyClass.fromJson

Comment: I'm not worried about deserialization, but that's good to know.  TypeScript has helped a Java programmer more easily ease his way into Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stringify it send it over an HTTP connection. In most cases (depending on the framework you're using), if the response header is `application/json` and you just pass a plain old JavaScript object, whatever implementation you're using will generally take care of the encoding for you (this is unless you're dealing with an extremely low-level interface, which it doesn't appear that you are).

Just do something like this:

```
let order_json = { order: order };

WhateverHTTPLibraryYoureUsing.send(order_json);
```

You mentioned Angular in the comments, so that would look something like:

```
$http.post(yourEndpoint, { order: order });

// or $http.post(yourEndpoint, { order }); if using ecmascript6
```